# can I install wiring pi libraries on my desktop linux PC?

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries

I have a project I'm working on, that will eventually be a raspberry pi running Ubuntu also, but right now I just want to write code that includes wiringPi.h, and wiringSerial.h
I tried installing wiringpi `sudo apt-get install wiringpi`, but this did not evidently include the C/C++ libraries for wiringpi.

how can I get the wiringpi C/C++ libraries installed on my ubuntu desktop?
the only hardware I am using is a serial port, there shouldn't be any issues with available GPIO.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libwiringpi-dev

Answer (score 1):

It was steel drivers comment, that solved it.
`sudo apt-get install libwiringpi-dev`

There are some issues with libwiringpi-dev.
You don't want to call wiringPiSetup(); you'll probably get

```
Oops: Unable to determine board revision from /proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision
or from /proc/cpuinfo
 -> No "Hardware" line
 ->  You'd best google the error to find out why.
```

which the reason is you're using a non arm based CPU,and the file its looking at isn't formatted the way it expects. fortunately I don't require any of that, I just wanted to use the simple serial port library.

I also had trouble with sending data via serialPuts(), but I don't need to do the handshaking.. I guess.

This is a little project that reads an Arduino uno with 2 potentiometers and a button, the goal is to use the pots to draw pictures on a screen, or in an image...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>       //read function
#include <string.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h> //simple serial port library

using namespace std;
//compiled with g++ -Wall -o readSerial   readSerial.cpp -lwiringPi

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const char *SensorPort = "/dev/ttyACM0"; //Serial Device Address
     
    int levelSensor = serialOpen(SensorPort, 9600);
    //serialPuts(levelSensor, "1"); //Send command to the serial device

    while (1){
        char buffer[100];
        ssize_t length = read(levelSensor, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (length == -1){
            cerr << "Error reading from serial port" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (length == 0){
            cerr << "No more data" << endl;
            break;
        }else{
            buffer[length] = '\0';
            cout << buffer; //Read serial data
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the data being sent via the Arduino is via this code:

```
    /*EtchaSketch
     * 2 pots, X,Y, increment
     * 
     * add a button to delete this shtuff
     * This program communicates on the serial port, to a separate program that handles the drawing of received coordinates (pot values).  
    */
    
    int potX = A0;    
    int potY = A1;    
    int sensorValX = 0;  
    int sensorValY = 0;  
    int del = 1;       //a button on pin 1 for deleting drawn content 
    int delbutton = 0;
    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        pinMode(del, INPUT);
    }

   void loop() {
      // read the value from the pots:
      if(digitalRead(del) == HIGH ){
          delbutton=1;
          }else{
              delbutton=0;
          }   
      sensorValX = analogRead(potX);
      sensorValY = analogRead(potY);
      Serial.print(sensorValX);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(sensorValY);
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.println(delbutton);
      delay(1000);
      }
```

and here it is working good enough to go into the parsing / drawing program
[image: Reading serial with wiringpi wiringSerial.h]